# How to list the names of PyPI packages corresponding to imports in a script?

Tags: python, import, installation, pypi

Is there a way to list the **PyPi package** names which correspond to modules being imported in a script?

For instance to import the module [`scapy3k`](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy) (this is its name) I need to use

```
import scapy.all
```

but the actual package to install is `scapy-python3`. The latter is what I am looking to extract from what I will find in the `import` statement (I do not care about its name - `scapy3k` in that case).

There are other examples (which escape me right now) of packages which have a `pip install` name completely different from what is being used in the `import` afterwards.

Comment: Do you need to find the name of a module you have already installed or a module you have to install?

Comment: @Francesco: this is a good point. I would rather say a module I need to install. The typical use case is a script which was developed on system A and which needs to be installed on system B (different OS). There is a bunch of `import`, for which relevant packages must be installed. So the names of yet-non-installed packages are what is needed.

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't think of a way to do this.

Comment: If you are in a virtual environment, perform pip freeze on the system that has the module installed.  The results will get you the names to use with pip to install elsewhere. Even if not in venv, but the list will be longer!

Comment: The module is called `scapy` (what you use in `import`). `scapy3k` is a fork name. PyPI package name is `scapy-python3` (what you `pip install`). Usually, all three are the same.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian "Usually, all three are the same". I find that the package name is usually different from the module name, if only to differentiate between python 2 and 3.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: (forgot to add to my previous comment)  A search for `scapy` on PyPi gives you a bunch of hits, including `scapy` packages for python 2 and 3.

Comment: @WoJ 1- you can disprove my statement  by looking at PyPI (though I believe the data is on my side).  Collect top-level (non-stdlib) module names on your system and see how many packages you can find using `pip install module_name` 2- There is no need to differentiate between Python 2 and 3 in many cases: common strategies to support both Python 2 and 3 do not require a separate package name. 3- `scapy` is not typical (see point 1-).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I am not saying that this is a rule, but there are exceptions (the example I gave is one). Therefore I cannot assume that `pip install name_of_module` will work.

Comment: @WoJ I know there are exceptions e.g., in addition to `scapy`, there are `python-dateutil`, `wxPython`, `pyOpenSSL`. The word *"usually"* does not imply that *all* packages follow the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name listed on pypi is the [name](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#setup-name) defined in the distribution's setup.py / setup.cfg file.  There is no requirement that this name relates to the name of the package that will be installed.  So there is no 100% reliable way to obtain the name of a distribution on pypi, given only the name of the package that it installs (the use case identified in the OP's comment).